# Selenium - How do I compare get_attribute value when it returns None [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am working with selenium for some automation and I was using get_attribute to compare values to assign whether a variable would be true or false.

So my question is, when I use get_attribute and it returns the value of 'None' ( This is expected since the element I am looking for does not exist), is that value returned as a String? And if it is, then my question would be, why am I unable to compare it as I would any other string.

```py
active_establishment = CRM_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gridBodyTable"]').get_attribute("records")
print(active_establishment)

if active_establishment == 'None':
    party[x].establishment = False
else:
    party[x].establishment = True
```

active_establishments = None

establishments = True (expected results should be False)

Comment: Hey guys...silly me. So I found a solution to my problem.

All I had to do was cast my active_establishment as a string and it works.
```pythonactive_establishment = str(CRM_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gridBodyTable"]').get_attribute("records"))```
This means that when get_attribute returns 'None', it is neither a null or a string. So what is it?

Comment: If the element does not exist you should receive, no such element exception rather `None`. Not sure how you are getting `None` here. However, the type is `NoneType`.

Comment: You can simplify your last 4 lines to `party[x].establishment = active_establishment != 'None'`.

Comment: If you no longer need this question, please delete it.

Comment: @JeffC Please take some time to read the placeholder text within the comment box which explicitly mentions to **avoid answering questions in comments**.

Comment: @JeffC Additionally, please don't spread **vandalism** by asking the OP to **delete** the question/post.

Comment: @SomronTouch Is your question resolved or you are still looking for an answer?

Comment: @DebanjanB You really need to read a LOT more carefully. My "answer" isn't an answer, it was an efficiency to some code he posted, not a full answer. That's why it's in the comments. Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the rules and read more carefully before you try to be the comment (and other) police.

Comment: @DebanjanB Again... you should stop using words like "vandalism", "spamming", etc. that you clearly don't understand. He said that he found his own answer and it was a simple typo/mistake. I said "IF" (note the IF), `>If< you no longer need this question, please delete it.` If there's no value in this question for the next person, it *should* be deleted. It's not vandalism, it's being responsible and cleaning up after yourself so others don't have to.

Comment: Hey guys, seems like I can't delete this post since people have invested time to answer it. I do hope this post can help someone else who stumbles upon it :)

thank you everyone

Comment: @JeffC : Somron's comment should be an eye opener for you where he have put a price on the time invested by the contributors to answer the question. After 6 years, you can start it right now. Good luck.

Comment: @DebanjanB What in the world are you talking about? You make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the comparison as below.

```
if active_establishment is None:
    party[x].establishment = False
else:
    party[x].establishment = True
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a lot more efficient than casting find_attribute as a string :)